# Is it worth to wait for Hydro?

Tags: ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still on Fuerte we are planning to upgrade. The question is whether to wait for Hydro or upgrade to Groovy now?

From our point of view this situation is as follows. We want to upgrade because of MoveIt package. That plays in favour of Groovy, MoveIt doesn't seems like it will change for Hydro and we would be able to upgrade now.

So, is there anything that should be considered?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66182/is-it-worth-to-wait-for-hydro?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally I think that depends on your reasons for the upgrade in general. Hydro should be released by the end of July (29th) unless there are further delays, so you'd be waiting just about a month longer.

If you don't intend to use any new features of hydro and if you don't care whether the packages of ROS are catkin or rosbuild I see no real need to wait for hydro. Just an assumption on my part, but I assume when you have custom packages it'll also be easier to stick to groovy first instead of going for hydro.

---

Originally posted by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) with karma: 73 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-06-28**:
Thanks, I have updated the question.

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-28**:
I now have updated my answer as well.

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-07-01**:
What are these new features of Hydro?

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-07-01**:
I'll be honest, I didn't bother to look enough yet, and wherever the features are mentioned, I didn't find them for myself yet. The one thing I know for sure is that with Hydro everything's catkinized.
Also there is this list of included packages: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro